# Pages not being unloaded from DOM when using index.html

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have two very simple pages as below.  If I browse to "mysite.com/" the webserver returns the "index.html" content, as is normal.  If I then click the "page2" link, jquery mobile loads the 2nd page into the DOM, but **doesn't** unload the first page from the DOM, although it is hidden (display:none) from view.

I now have 2 `<div data-role="page">` elements in the DOM, with only page2 page visible on screen.  If I then click the "index" link on page2, jquery mobile unloads page2 from the DOM, and loads the index.html page into a new DOM element.  I now have two instances of `<div id="index">` in the DOM which is obviously incorrect!

What is going on?   I thought I'd ask on here before reporting it as a bug but it seems like a very simple example that is completely broken!

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <a href="page2.html">Page2</a>
        <p>index page</p>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

page2.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page-2">
        <a href="index.html">Index</a>
        <p>Page 2</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: 
 I found a workaround of page2.html linking to  rather than "index.html", which prevents the 2nd duplicate loading, but it still seems wrong that the original page loaded is *always* kept in the DOM.

EDIT 2: This is a known issue https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4050 - I just didn't manage to find it despite extensive googling before posting this question.  I might raise a bug report against their documentation though, because it is highly unexpected behaviour IMO.

Comment: jQM keeps first page in DOM and loads/removes external pages. So removing external pages is normal as long as they aren't flagged to be cached. However, navigating to _index.html_ should take you back to first page not load it in DOM again.

Comment: Why always keep first page in the DOM?  Once navigated to page2, why not remove the first page, like any other page is?

Comment: Because it's the landing page (base), it removes any external page if not cached.

Comment: if you want to remove it from DOM, add `data-external-page="true"` to page div and then once created, flag it for removal `bindRemove`. demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/3ffWQAC764lHM7dMbBp9?p=preview

Comment: thanks Omar that works, if you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: This fix will work as long as `.page()` widget isn't completely replaced and removed by `.pagecontainer()` widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behavior of jQuery Mobile, first landing page is always kept in DOM. It only removes *external pages* which aren't cached `data-dom-cache="true"`. You will always have two pages in DOM, *landing page* and active *external page*.

Nevertheless, if you wish to remove *landing page* once you navigate to another page, add `data-external-page="true"` to page div of the *landing page*. Once it's created `pagecreate`, flag it for removal `.page("bindRemove")`. This is the way jQuery Mobile removes *external pages*.

**Note** that is fix will work as long as `.page()` widget isn't removed and replaced by `.pagecontainer()` widget.

```html
<div data-role="page" id="pageID" data-external-page="true">
```

```js
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageID", function (e) {
    $(e.target).page("bindRemove");
});
```

> [**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/3ffWQAC764lHM7dMbBp9?p=preview)

Comment: Hello @Omar, Sometimes I didn't have Id to the landing-page, what Should I do then?

Comment: @Sravan you can check URL or `data-url`. Also you can check if this page is first page in DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I created a test as described in your question with the two files `index.html` and `page2.html` and tested with Chrome (version 38.0).   I loaded `index.html` and then navigated to `page2.html` and then back to `index.html`.  Using Chrome Developer Tools, I then examined the elements in the page and found the following (screen shot):

[image: Screen shot of Elements/DOM]

As we see, there is one instance of the page called `index` and one instance of the page called `page-2` but no duplicates.

I realize that this does not line up with your own results but am offering this is an answer demonstrating that the story works as expected.  If we determine a flaw in the logic of this answer, I'll happily delete it.

Comment: @Omar Sorry sir, I don't understand the comment?   I visited the link and saw some HTML but am not understanding what you are trying to tell me?

Comment: the demo in my previous comments reproduces what the OP claims. Navigating to _index.html_ does load that page into DOM where it shouldn't. However, if you navigate using _#hash_ it doesn't load _index_ page, it just navigates normally. http://oi58.tinypic.com/ixcj8i.jpg

Comment: Assuming this is running on `http://localhost/`, if you type into your browser `http://localhost/index.html` then it works as you describe, if however you enter `http://localhost/` then it works as I describe.  I found a workaround of page2.html linking to `<a href= './'>` rather than "index.html", but it still seems wrong that the original page loaded is *always* kept in the DOM.

Comment: @Mark I think the design pattern behind jQuery mobile is that you have a set of pages on your mobile device that the user is going to switch between.  One of the design aspects of a mobile app is that of a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application As such, the belief is that you are going to switch "back" to a previous page after you have visited a subsequent page and hence it exchanges DOM caching and parsing in preference to cost of reloads.

Comment: That approach causes problems if you use the same IDs in separate pages, which is how I hit this in a much more complex situation than the example I posted.  I edited my question with a link to an issue I found against jQM that explains it as well.