# jquery mobile page replacement with Ajax Nav

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

In jquery mobile i have an index page, it has a tiny bit of PHP to decide to show login/logout etc.

So i have a link to another page that deals with logging in / out, this is done via ajax nav so my dom now looks like so

```
<div data-role:"page" id="home">.....</div>
<div data-role:"page" id="login">.....</div>
```

This is all fine, but now if i navigate back, my '#home' does not reflect the pages as php doesn't work like that....

but I can ajax nav back to the '#home' and this works fine, but now my dom looks like this:

```
<div data-role:"page" id="home">.....</div>
<div data-role:"page" id="login">.....</div>
<div data-role:"page" id="home" data-external-page="true">.....</div>
```

it functions Ok, but it's not neat. Are there any clever ways so that the new page replaces the old page?

would there be any problems with it as is?

thanks.

Comment: How do you go back to homepage? `href="url.com/index.html`? If yes, it's similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/26834528/1771795

Comment: yes, I just use href="index.html" instead of href="#home"

Comment: Use #home or href="./" in order not to load same page into DOM.