# Prevent multiple divs with same id

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am having a problem in a jquery-mobile project that uses multiple html docs. The premise is that normal flow, a user would come into the home page they then link to one of two other pages (icon_view, detail_view). From there the user can select a "character". My understanding of jQM has it that the home page is loaded, when a link to icon_view or detail_view is clicked, that HTML is loaded and everything except the <title> and <div data-role="page"> are stripped, and the  is placed into the DOM. This is working fine. This happens again when the user clicks one of the characters <div data-role="page" id="CH-page"> is the div that is inserted into the DOM. If I click back, and then select another character, everything works great. When the user bookmarks a character page however and tries to navigate to another character page, it seems like there is a second <div data-role="page" id="CH-page"> that is added to the DOM again, and any manipulation by ID of the objects appears to have no effect, (I am guessing that it is because the 1st instance is the one being changed, but is not visible). My question is in navigation how do I prevent multiple <div data-role="page" id="CH-page"> in my document?

character.php

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime();
$ts = "?x=" . $date->getTimestamp();
$typeId = $_GET["typeId"];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HARDAC - Character</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/borg.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/hardac.css<?php echo $ts ?>" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index_data.js<?php echo $ts ?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/hardac.js<?php echo $ts ?>"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="CH-page">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/character.css<?php echo $ts ?>" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/character.js<?php echo $ts ?>"></script>
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <div class="ui-btn-left">
        <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-inline ui-icon-carat-l">Back</a>
        <a href="index.php" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-inline ui-icon-home"></a>
    </div>
    <h1>HARDAC - Character</h1>
</div> <!-- data-role="header" -->
<div class="ui-content" id="CH-content">
        <div>
            <div class="CH-picture">
                <img src="" alt="" name="CH-picture" id="CH-picture"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="field-contain">
            <label for="CH-player-name">Player Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="CH-player-name" id="CH-player-name" placeholder="Player Name"/>
        </div>
        <div data-role="field-contain">
            <label for="CH-character-name">Character Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="CH-character-name" id="CH-character-name" placeholder="Character Name"/>
        </div>
        <div data-role="field-contain">
            <label for="CH-creature-type" class="select">Creature Type:</label>
            <select name="CH-creature-type" id="CH-creature-type">
                <option value="0">Unknown</option>
                <option value="1">Changeling</option>
                <option value="2">Werewolf</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div data-role="field-contain">
            <label for="CH-virtue" class="select">Virtue:</label>
            <select name="CH-virtue" id="CH-virtue">
                <option value="0">Unknown</option>
                <option value="3">Charity</option>
                <option value="4">Faith</option>
                <option value="5">Fortitude</option>
                <option value="6">Hope</option>
                <option value="7">Justice</option>
                <option value="8">Prudence</option>
                <option value="9">Temperance</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div data-role="field-contain">
            <label for="CH-vice" class="select">Vice:</label>
            <select name="CH-vice" id="CH-vice">
                <option value="0">Unknown</option>
                <option value="10">Envy</option>
                <option value="11">Gluttony</option>
                <option value="12">Greed</option>
                <option value="13">Lust</option>
                <option value="14">Pride</option>
                <option value="15">Sloth</option>
                <option value="16">Wrath</option>
            </select>
        </div>
<?php
if ($typeId == 1) {
    include("changeling.php");
} else if ($typeId == 2) {
    include("werewolf.php");
}
?>
    </div>
</div> <!-- class="ui-content" -->
<div data-role="footer">
</div> <!-- data-role="footer" -->
</div> <!-- data-role="page" -->
</body>
</html>
```

character.js

```
var character = null;
var player = null;

$(document).off("pageinit", "#CH-page").on("pageinit", "#CH-page", function (event) {
var parameters = $(this).data("url").split("?")[1];

var characterId = getUrlParameter(parameters, "characterId"); // gets characterId either from jQM or browser url
character = getCharacter(characterId);
player = getPlayer(character.playerId);

fillSelect("CH-creature-type", character.typeId);
fillSelect("CH-vice", character.viceId);
fillSelect("CH-virtue", character.virtueId);
if (player.picture) {
    $("#CH-picture").attr("src", "img/" + player.picture + "");
}
$("#CH-picture").attr("alt", player.name);
$("#CH-player-name").val(player.name);
$("#CH-character-name").val(character.name);
$("#CH-page").trigger("create");
});

function fillSelect(selectId, selectedId) {
 $("#" + selectId).each(function(){ $(this).val(selectedId); });
}
```

Comment: This is a bug in jQM 1.4 in single page model. I'd suggest using class rather than IDs. Also, always refer to active page by using `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage")`. Edit: try this https://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/a85fxf1r/

Comment: A workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26834528/1771795

Comment: Have you tried any of the aforementioned possible solutions?

Comment: @Omar, no I ended up using `$(document).on('pagehide', '.ui-page', function(event, ui) {
    $(event.target).remove();
});`

Comment: `pagecontainerhide` ;) Good workaround. Post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will remove any page when it is hidden instead of possibly leaving it in the document tree.

```
$(document).on('pagehide', '.ui-page', function(event, ui) { 
    $(event.target).remove();
});
```